# Changing the IP of a single-instance EB environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment with a single instance and I'd like to change its IP Address. But every time I disassociate the EIP from the instance, it keeps reassigning itself after a few seconds. The same thing happens when I try to associate a different address with the instance (by ticking the "Allow Elastic IP to be reassociated if already attached" checkbox).

What am I missing? Is it even possible to change the IP of a single instance EB environment?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a best practice to make changes to your production Elastic Beanstalk infrastructure directly.

Create a new single instance EB environment and deploy your code to it.  Assign it a new Elastic IP and verify it us up and running correctly.  Yes, this means for a short amount of time, you will have your app running in production on 2 separate instances.

Once you verify everything is in place, delete the old environment and that previous IP address should go away with it.  You should be left with your new environment.  Update the Route 53 or your DNS provider to point to the new environment.